# Unparseable date: "Wed Dec 19 10:21:46 UYT 2018"

Tags: java

Trying to get some date store in a database, but I´m getting parse errors.
This is what I got:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
date = dateFormat.parse("Wed Dec 19 10:21:46 UYT 2018");
```

I get the error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Dec 19 10:21:46 UYT 2018"
```

Comment: Try `new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH)`   .

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your error](https://rextester.com/IPIM81148).  Your codes looks OK to me.

Comment: It worked fine with Locale.ENGLISH. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out "EEE" is more accurate for printing day of the week also you should use default Locale

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    final Date date = dateFormat.parse("Wed Dec 19 10:21:46 UYT 2018");
  }
}
```